# can't add a file or application to /system/xbin of andriod

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, adb, android-source

i am having problem regarding to insertion or push anything from computer to the android AVD(install and build using AOSP) on Linux operating system.
the error i as follows.

## error:Read only file system.

i have able to use adb shell and the adb su. but no luck.

Comment: Please read the guide on [how to write a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question with more information.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
adb root
adb remount
```

there's no su program in Android.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `system` partition on Android is mounted as `ro`: Read-Only.
You need superuser permissions(I find SuperSU nice).
I had rooted my Nexus 4 and on that I had used this command(in a superuser shell):

```
mount -o remount,rw /system
```

You might want to install a terminal application(like [Termux](https://www.google.com.ng/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwikodOdmu7PAhXErI8KHVOxDtcQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.termux%26hl%3Den&usg=AFQjCNFQhEyI-uCyG1t_N-A9dUzFZEurjw)) for testing. Run `su` in a terminal to get root access(prompt should now look like `blahblahblah #`)
An app by Chainfire(SuperSU creator), with root access, gives `adb shell` auto-root access. You might want to find it quick, a warning had been given that CHinfire might make it paid-for at anytime.
You shouldn't be able to do this to an Android emulator.